# Switch between USB and Bluetooth module TTL

Tags: usb, bluetooth, ttl

In my project I have an MCU that I want to communicate with via 5V TTL serial. I have two methods of doing this in my circuit, USB via an FT232R (5V) and Bluetooth via an HC-05 module and level shifter (TXS0102, 3.3V <-> 5V).

In order to switch between the two sources, I have implemented a MAX4525 analogue switch IC which is operated using the 5V supply from the USB on the logic switch but supplied from a different 5V source. Is this a valid design?

[image: MAX4525 TTL source switch]

EDIT: Relevant parts of the schematic...

[image: USB and Bluetooth TTL signals]

---

Edit: A different approach. Power the FT232R from the internal 5V supply. Use the same 3.3V supplied to the reset pin for switching the MAX4525 chip. I believe this way the MAX4525L will always be within spec?
[image: Self powered FT232R]

Comment: Show the whole schematic...

Comment: @laptop2d - wider schematic uploaded as requested. Thanks

Comment: Technically the MAX4524 like many ICs is not rated to have signals which exceed its supply, so if your supplies are not coordinated you may want to think about that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Good point. Maybe it would be better to supply it from the 12V source.

Comment: @JoeMann - the 12v source isn't necessarily any more coordinated in the time of its presence with the USB supply than the 5v derived from the 12v would be.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Indeed but the rest of the circuit depends on the 12V supply anyway (MCU etc.) so I think it's safe to assume the 12V supply is going to be there. As I understand it, and you rightly pointed out, the signals can't exceed the supply voltage for this chip so if it was supplied from the 12V source, 5V signals should be fine?

Comment: @JoeMann No, it doesn't all depend on the 12v input.  Look at where the USB chip gets its power.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I'm only interested in using the USB interface when the cable is plugged in, the rest of the time I intend to use the Bluetooth module which is why the Tx and Rx lines from the Bluetooth module are connected to the NC contacts on the MAX4525. The intention is that when a USB cable is connected, the USB interface chip is powered and the Tx and Rx signals are switched over to USB instead of Bluetooth.

Comment: If the USB is plugged in to a powered host but your device's power is off, technically you are violating the chip ratings.  Adding some series resistors could soften that a bit, though not necessarily bring it into spec.

Comment: Also a good point. I would say that's probably something I can live with but in order to avoid being out of spec I'm thinking an optocoupler operated from USBVCC to raise the logic input may be one way to go?

Comment: Your USB VCC signal should be coming from the other side of the bead. You probably also want a pull down on pin6 U5